# More then one Localized string is not allowing in UIAlertView

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uialertview

I tried to do localization. It's Working fine, but here, I am facing a problem in UIAlertView. It's not working for more then one string, but I need to keep more then one string AlertView OtherButton Titles.

```
UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"AlertTitle", @"")
                                                        message:NSLocalizedString(@"AlertMessage", @"")
                                                       delegate:nil
                                              cancelButtonTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"AlertCancel", @"")
                                              otherButtonTitles:NSLocalizedString(@"AlertOk", @""), nil];
```

Comment: which error you have get? Can you explain in detail, so I can identify problem and try to find solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following piece of code.

```
UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"AlertTitle", nil) message:NSLocalizedString(@"AlertMessage", nil) delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Cancel", nil) otherButtonTitles:NSLocalizedString(@"Change Password", nil), NSLocalizedString(@"Profile", nil), NSLocalizedString(@"log out", nil), nil];
[alertView show];
```

Comment: Can we get an explanation on why this works or what was wrong with the example.

Answer (score 1):

```
UIAlertView *alert =  [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",NSLocalizedString(@"AlertTitle",nil)] message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",NSLocalizedString(@"AlertMessage",nil)] delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",NSLocalizedString(@"AlertCancel",nil)] otherButtonTitles:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",NSLocalizedString(@"AlertOk",nil)], nil];
```

Comment: ,Thank you, but i need to more then one string for OtherButton Titles.

Comment: Here the actual thing is   otherButtonTitles:(@"Change Password", @"Profile", @"log out",@"cancel",  nil]; so i need to change localization this buttons

Comment: yes try this [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@,%@,%@",NSLocalizedString(@"Profile",@"Change Password",@"log out",nil)]

Answer (score 0):

To simplify all NSLocalizedString calls, I use this technic

```
#define Trad(string, ...)  [NSString  stringWithFormat: NSLocalizedString(string, nil), ##__VA_ARGS__]
```

Then you can create your AlertView like this:

```
UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:Trad(@"Title")
                                                    message:Trad(@"Message")
                                                    delegate:nil
                                           cancelButtonTitle:Trad(@"Cancel")
                                           otherButtonTitles:Trad(@"Button1"),
                                                             Trad(@"Button2"),
                                                             Trad(@"Button3"), nil];
```

The #define statement isn't necessary, it's only purpose is to simplify the code.

Comment: Trad also Use for Localization?

Comment: I don't understand your question ^^